# Removing Rows Based on Criteria in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to exclude rows from my list that meet certain criteria. For example, an Identifier that starts with a "C" rather than a number. I'm able to see all the rows that meet this criteria, but I'm not sure how to remove/exclude the rows.

I know `.remove()` would work, but I'm not calling the list correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import re
import csv


def main(argv):
    my_iterator = iter(sys.stdin.readline, "")
    next(my_iterator)

    for row in csv.reader(my_iterator):
        my_list = my_iterator

        #Delete rows that have InvoiceNo that start with C
        if re.match(r'C', row[0]):
            my_list.remove()
            print("yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your loop to append a row to your list only if the first column does not start with `'C'`:

```
my_list = []
for row in csv.reader(my_iterator):
    if not row[0].startswith('C'):
        my_list.append(row)
```

Comment: Maybe I just need more coffee, but I can't understand why `for row in csv.reader(my_iterator):` is in there twice?

Comment: Oops that was a typo. Fixed then.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize list comprehension and `startswith()` here to build a new list;

```
my_list = [row for row in csv.reader(my_iterator) if not row[0].startswith('C')]
```